# Does it make sense to install a fan at an A/C register to draw more airflow on a slow branch?

Tags: hvac

My house has always had a problem with airflow to the back bathroom.  The 6" pipe in this image is the feed from the main hallway to the back bathroom.  House designed in 1973.

It seems the only way I can increase airflow to that bathroom would be to put a fan on the register or prior to register to draw the air from the main hallway at a higher rate.  I figure I can add a fan with a relay switch controlled by a thermostat through Home Assistant to kick in when the conditions are such that it would be needed.

Is adding a fan to the register a thing that actually happens as a solution for poor airflow?

[image: Utility Room HVAC]

Comment: Is there space in the joist bay for a fatter supply duct?

Comment: It's called a "duct booster fan", I don't know how well it would solve your problem. But increasing the 6" as ThreePhaseEel suggests is a better starting point, if possible.

Comment: It runs through a soffit that has plenty of space, so creating a larger duct is probably an option.

Comment: Is the door to the bathroom shut most of the time? Also, do you have a return air duct for the bathroom? If the door is closed most of the time and there is no return air duct, you would probably see bigger gains in temperature evenness if you add a new tap off the return air ducting for the bathroom or were able to leave the door open.

Comment: Is the problem only that you want the bathroom warmer in the winter or do you also want more cool, dry air in the cooling season? If you mainly want to dry the bathroom after showering, you could just set the air handler fan to ON during the morning and evening showering times. Also put the bathroom exhaust fan on a timer.

Comment: Based on your comment under an answer, "and no returns in the entire system", Your system may be starved of air flow due to undersized return/intake all around, and spaces with easiest flow-through dominate the flow. How much space is under the bathroom door?

Answer (score 2):

You could partially or totally shut the vents in rooms that **are** the correct temp.

This would force higher air flow into your back bathroom.

Comment: Might also be dampers in the ducts to tune the air flow.

Comment: I was considering building my own registers with micro controllers and servos to create automated dampers that would shift position based upon sensors in each room...overkill, but fun.

Comment: @JonGriffith Automatic damper systems are a thing (and they are usually pretty expensive). It's kind of like putting a Ferrari engine into $500 jalopy. It might be better to fix the root problem and pay a pro to re-duct the house with proper return air venting if you want to go that route so you get better heating/cooling passively vs. spending all that time and/or money on a sophisticated damper system for an underperforming HVAC system.

Answer (score 2):

My experience with those duct booster fans is that they make noise and do very little to increase the air flow. I would increase the air flow with a larger duct. Also, If that 6" duct was installed in the main trunk with a "starting collar" instead of a "side or top take off" that could also add to a lower air flow than normal.

Comment: I think this is a point the OP should pat attention to. He is tapping off the main duct, where there is low pressure but high flow, and a take off would be more appropriate. Frankly 6" seems large enough already. That, and he needs a return vent, exit vent or proper spacing under the door.

Comment: or external vent an make-up air.

Answer (score 1):

Final discoveries and implemented solution:

I disassembled my house to find out how it was built in 1973.  The 6" round duct that fed the back bathroom (poorly) was a standard galvanized duct that had been cut in the shape of a scoop, and inserted into the main HVAC duct about half-way across the width of the duct.

My solution, which seems to be working quite well, was to reduce this from 6" to 4" and re-route the duct using a flexible insulated duct through the 6" gap in the utility wall.  Rather than assembling a shoddy galvanized ducting solution, slicing my hands off, and dying from blood loss, I thought this solution would work the best.

Seems it has.  Despite the reduction in diameter, cold air makes it back to that location without fail and I've managed to preserve the idea of eliminating the soffit.

Answer (score 0):

Focusing on the supply line in order to address insufficient HVAC flow is a very common thing to do. However, often the problem can be with a lack of return air (especially if there is no return air vent as is common bathrooms of older homes).

Simple Experiment to Drive the Point Home:

1. Blow through a straw and put your finger over the other end -- there isn't much air coming out, is there?
2. With your finger still over the end, blow through a straw harder (add a booster fan) -- there isn't much air coming out, is there?
3. Blow through a bigger straw (increase the supply line) and keep your finger over the outlet -- did this improve the flow rate much?
4. Now, go back to the original straw and take your finger away a bit (increase the outlet / "return air")  -- now you get a lot more air flow through the straw. Note that increasing the straw size (supply line) or blowing hard (booster fan) would help increase airflow even more now.

If there is no return air vent in the bathroom to pull air out of the bathroom, that would be the place to start as the best bang for your buck in gains from doing HVAC work. Otherwise, trying to decrease the resistance of the air circuit (increase size of supply/return lines) would be the next best change since it passively decreases the resistance of the lines to increase air flow through the room. Finally, if none of those are an option, then a booster fan could be worth trying to increase the air flow through the room, but it will likely marginally increase airflow in the room (depending on how good the booster fan is, other restrictions in the system), will require additional electricity to operate, and probably still won't be as effective as the other solutions.

Comment: So the idea is to simulate creating a void, or a vacuum IN the target room (i.e. return air suction) so there's a reduction in volume and an actual place for the air in that 6" tube to spill into, which would increase flow.  Unfortunately, there is a single intake in the hallway soffit and no returns in the entire system besides that.

Comment: Do you leave the bathroom door closed most of the time? If not, I would start there by leaving it open when not in use if possible (giving it a path back to the hallway return vent).

Comment: The idea is not to create a vacuum in the room itself specifically, but rather give a way to complete the air circuit (ideally, the pressure in the room is balanced). You seem familiar with electronics, so I’ll go with the electrical analogy: If you have a “hot” electrical wire (air supply in this analogy) and a light bulb with no neutral wire attached (room with no return air vent) then there is nowhere for the electrons to flow because there is no difference in electrical potential (air pressure in the analogy). Once potential/pressure equalizes with the supply, then flow ceases.